# sassMiddleware compile in vercel with dynamically added scss file

Tags: node.js, sass, vercel

Issue - Access dynamically added file in tmp folder in vercel

Its a serverless platform in vercel for API managing

**Nodejs**
Im using sassMiddleware module for scss compile dynamically from server and everything is worked but not compiling to css  if scss file is created dynamically

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    /* Options */
    src: path.join(__dirname, 'tmp'),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'tmp'),
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed',
    prefix: '/prefix'  // 
}));
app.use('/tmp', express.static(__dirname + '/tmp'));


// Call from frontend
<link rel="stylesheets" href="prefix/style.css"/>
```

If there **style.scss** file in tmp folder , it will automatically compile to style.css

but in my case I have to create a style.scss file dynamically but not compiling into css in vercel but working in localhost if style.css added dynamically

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await fse.writeFile(`/tmp/style.scss`, "body{background:blue; color:red;}");
        res.send('Hey this is my API running 1 ')
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error.message)
    }

})


// Call from frontend - it wil work from localhost but not working in vercel
<link rel="stylesheets" href="prefix/style.css"/>
```

Thank you